# Does different the initial prior result in the same posterior of a Kalman filter as time goes to infinity, why?

Tags: bayesian, kalman-filter

Let $p(x_0) \in \{p_i(x_0)\colon i\in {\mathcal I}\}=:{\mathcal P}$ be the prior of a discrete-time Kalman filter, where ${\mathcal P}$ is the family of  nondegenerated Gaussian distributions. Then firstly, does the following limit exist (l.i.m. means covergence in the mean square sense) for every $i \in {\mathcal I}$?

\begin{equation}
\lim_{t \to \infty} \|p_i(x_t|y_t,\ldots,y_1)-p_j(x_t|y_t,\ldots,y_1)\| = 0, \quad \forall i,j \in {\mathcal I}
\end{equation}
where $y_t$'s are observations. $p_i$ means using $p_i(x_0)$ as the prior. $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the function norm.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, being more explicit might help. For instance, you could say which type of Kalman Filter (e.g. discrete plant, continuous plant with continuous filter or continuous plant with discrete filter) and priors are you talking about. But anyway, I found this book "Optimal and Robust Estimation" by Lewis, Xie and Popa very useful for Kalman filters. You might check chapters 2 and 3, is all very detailed and readable.

Comment: Thanks for the kind reply. I think mathematically, the discrete Kalman filter and Kalman-Bucy filter (continuous time parameter) have the same nature. There are some studies for the convergence of the posterior in the field of Bayesian inference, but the results are quite limited (e.g., the state space is countably infinite). For the Kalman filter, I am still finding the corresponding results...

Comment: I would really like to answer your question, but I don't quite get it. Could you try to pose it in standard Kalman Filter terms? You know, with reference to the states, the measurements, the dynamic model, etc. For instance, are your distributions about the states, the measurements, or the model? I think if you restate the question that way you´ll find more people able to answer it.

Comment: Thanks moonshine, and I have already find the answer. It is just given on the book you recommended (see Theorem 2.3 in Section 2.5.3). If the system is reachable and detectable, then the posteriori is independent on the priori. Actually, this is an important reason why the Kalman filter is famous.

Comment: This problem is also known as the stability of a filter. Recently, statisticians give the rigorous proof for the convergence (in a.s. sense) of the posterior for nonlinear filters. But still, there are several constraints for the system (see "observability and nonlinear filtering" by Ramon van Handel as an example). I would say Kalman and Bucy did a genious work, since their results are suitable for "unstable" signal, which is a very hard issue for nonlinear filter even for elite statisticans today. It is hard to believe that Kalman and Bucy can derive such an amazing result 50 years ago.

Comment: By the way, how to give you this 50 bounty. The book you recommended helped me to find out this answer.

Comment: It's good to see you could solve your problem. I can "answer" the question with the same arguments of the Theorem 2.3 and you could grant me the bounty. Thanks in advance :). In that way other people might also benefit from reading this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is based on the book "Optimal and Robust Estimation" by Lewis, Xie and Popa. Let's say you have this a system with the dynamics:
$$x_{k+1}=A_kx_k+B_ku_k+G_kw_k$$
Where $u_k$ is the input and $w_k$ is a Gaussian noise. Also, let the observation equation be:
$$z_k=H_kx_k+v_k$$
Now again, $v_k$ is a Gaussian noise process. Your prior for the states would traditionaly be also Gaussian, i.e.:
$$x_0\sim(\bar{x}_0,P_{x0})$$
You initialize the system like
$$P_0=P_{x0},\;\hat{x}_0=\bar{x}_0$$
From now on, a minus as a superscript indicates the estimate without measurement correction, right? Well in the "a priori recursive formulation" the estimates for the mean of the states (without measurements) and the "Kalman Gain" $K_k$ are given by:
$$x^{\mathbf{-}}_{k+1}=A(I-K_kH_k)x^{\mathbf{-}}_{k}+B_ku_k+A_kK_kz_k$$
$$K_k=P^{\mathbf{-}}_{k}H_k^T(H_kP^{\mathbf{-}}_{k}H^T_k+R_k)$$
$P^{\mathbf{-}}_{k}$, the estimate of the covariance in the step $k$, is calculated through:
$$P_{k+1}^{\mathbf{-}}=A[P^{\mathbf{-}}_{k}-P^{\mathbf{-}}_{k}H_k^T(H_kP^{\mathbf{-}}_{k}H_k^T+R_k)^{-1}HP^{\mathbf{-}}_{k}]A_k^T+G_kQ_kG^T_k$$
Here, $R_k$ is the covariance matrix of $v_k$ and $Q_k$ the one of $w_k$.
After each observation you perform the "measurment update". Now, under this formulation, we can go to relevan part of theorem 2.3 in section 2.5.3. In this theorem the processes are assumed to be stationary, so the dynamic matrices and the noise covariances are fixed (independent of $k$), in such conditions

> Let $\sqrt{Q}$ be a square root of the process noise covariance so that $Q=\sqrt{Q}\sqrt{Q}^T\geq 0$, and let the measurement noise have $R>0$. Suppose $(A,G\sqrt{Q})$ is reachable. Then $(A,H)$ is detectable if and only if
>
> 1. There is a unique positive definite limiting solution $P$ to the states   covariance equation (2.61 in the book), which is independent of the prior $P_0$. Furthermore, $P$ is the unique positive definite solution to the algebraic Riccati equation.
>    ...

I hope this answers your question, dear Ryan.

Comment: Dear Moonshine, thank you very much!